# containerd: Unable to overwrite sandbox image

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, containerd

**System**

Ubuntu 22.04.01

kubeadm v1.25.4

containerd 1.6.10

**Description**

I'm trying to setup k8s 1.25.4 with a private docker repository and the containerd runtime.

I followed the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) to overwrite the sandbox image in `/etc/containerd/config.toml`:

```
...
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
  sandbox_image = "my-private-registry:5000/registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8"
...
```

Afterwards, the containerd service, and later the machine, was restarted.

However, when trying to initialize the k8s cluster with kubeadm (`kubeadm init --config cluster-config.yml`), the initalization failed with `journalctl -exu containerd` showing the following output:

```
Dec 14 11:04:00 myhost containerd[866]: time="2022-12-14T11:04:00.911273848Z" level=info msg="trying next host" error="failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/pause/manifests/3.6\": dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout" host=registry.k8s.io
Dec 14 11:04:00 myhost containerd[866]: time="2022-12-14T11:04:00.927516068Z" level=error msg="RunPodSandbox for &PodSandboxMetadata{Name:myhost,Uid:c4ebaf5ac4e21e7bc99cda96857ec39e,Namespace:kube-system,Attempt:0,} failed, error" error="failed to get sandbox image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/pause/manifests/3.6\": dial tcp 34.107.244.51:443: i/o timeout"
```

This indicates to me that the sandbox image overwrite was unsuccessful. `cluster-config.yml` is configured to use the private registry and kubeadm can succesfully pull the k8s images (including the sandbox image):

```
...
imageRepository: my-private-registry:5000
...
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try to add "version = 2" to your "/etc/containerd/config.toml".

Comment: did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, for me, I add the `version = 2` config in `/etc/containerd/config.toml` and it works:

```
version = 2
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
   config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
  #sandbox_image = "k8s.m.daocloud.io/pause:3.6"
  sandbox_image = "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6"
```

check the new sandbox image address:

```
[root@k8sslave01 ~]# crictl info|grep pause
    "sandboxImage": "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6",
```

this is the official config doc: https://github.com/containerd/cri/blob/master/docs/config.md